# I am trying to replay a pcap file that someone else captured for me (Im assuming they used tcpdump)

Tags: pcap, tcpreplay

Linux command:

```
tcpreplay -i replay -L 60000 -p 1000 20160627-ssmon01.pcap
```

Output:

```
sending out replay
processing file: 20160627-080001-ssmon01-napa0.pcap

Fatal Error: Error opening pcap file: unknown file format
```

I do not understand why this is happening? Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Best to run **tcpcapinfo** which comes with the Tcpreplay suite. It is designed to identify what is wrong with corrupted files rather than to simply give you info regarding file that are not corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to open it with tcpdump?

If not and if you have wireshark installed, use the capinfos utility that is included with wireshark to see what format the file is in.  The command is

```
 capinfos mypcap.pcap
```

You can then use wireshark, tshark or mergecap to change the format to something tcprelay can read. For example:

```
mergecap myin.pcap -w myout.pcap -F pcap
```